# TS2345: Argument of type '(number | undefined)[] is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<NumberValue>

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, d3.js, charts

I am using  D3.js library to create a scale for a bar chart's y-axis. The yBar scale is created using the d3.scaleLinear() function, which returns a linear scale that maps input values to output values.

Here is the code

```
    let yBar = scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3Array.max(datasets, d => d3Array.sum([d.asia, d.usa, d.uk]))]);
```

But typescript gives the error :

```
 TS2345: Argument of type '(number | undefined)[] is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<NumberValue>'`
```

Comment: I'm not a Typescript expert but does adding the non-null assertion to the array element expressions make a difference?

Comment: can you provide you solution here cause I don't get it

Comment: `[d.asia!, d.usa!, d.uk!]` in the call to `d3Array.sum()`

Answer (score 0):

D3js's [Array.max](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v3.2.3/README.md#max) can return `undefined` if there are no comparable values, which is why the type of your array passed to `.domain` is `number | undefined`.

If you know your array is never empty, one option is to tell Typescript the return type is a number with `as`.

```
let yBar = scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([
        0,
        d3Array.max(datasets, d => d3Array.sum([d.asia, d.usa, d.uk])) as number
    ]);
```

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: @TheDeadMan take some time to debug your own code and read errors, don't ignore them. What line is the error pointing to? What is the type of `height`?

Comment: @AndyRay from the error, it looks like the complaint is about the parameter being passed into `.sum()`, that array of property references. (*e:* or at least it might be)

Comment: the error point to  `.sum()` function